# Change UITextView Keyboard Appearance globally in app delegate

Tags: swift, uikit

I have seen this answered for `UITextField`, but I cannot seem to find a clear answer for changing `keyboardAppearance` in the app delegate for `UITextView`. Is this even possible?

```
UITextView.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

Causes a crash

Comment: What's the issue with what you're doing?

Comment: I have custom dark / light mode in my app, so I want to change all my UITextViews keyboard appearances at the same time from my app delegate. When I use the code above my app will crash.

Comment: What _is_ the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiecning the same bad behaviour.

After place in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UITextView.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

Once a UITextView has to appear on screen, this next error is triggered:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Have you sent -setKeyboardAppearance: to <UITextView: 0x7ff31113e000; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = '"Enter an optional commen...'; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000209fb10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ecc740>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 37}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> off the main thread? To verify, look for a complaint in the logs: "Unsupported use of UIKit…", and fix the problem if you find it. If your use is main-thread only please file a radar on UIKit, and attach this log. exercisedImplementations = {
    "setKeyboardAppearance:" =     (
    );
}'
```

That's strange cause UITextView follows protocol UITextInputTraits that allows us to deffine the default keyboard appearance.

Any help would be appreciated.

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift) [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) [uitextview](/questions/tagged/uitextview) [uiappearance](/questions/tagged/uiappearance)